# HTML/CSS website hosting

Tags: html, css, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I would like to host my HTML/CSS website (actually, just one page, but it may grow). Since I don't need PHP, MySQL or such things, I don't want to spend much. Is there anything out there? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only using HTML/CSS with no server side languages or database used then any webhost will do. Literally any one as all webhosts can serve up static pages. So do some research to see which has good reviews and a good price and you'll be all set.

Comment: Since I don't need PHP/MySQL, I'd like to spend *less* than those using them. Don't know if it possible anymore.

Comment: It really isn't. Hosting is such a commodity that prices can't get really lower even if you take features away.

Comment: Yep. It doesn't actually save the webhost any money to offer separate hosting plans just for static sites. Server-side scripting is so standard/commonplace now that there's really no point setting up a webserver without it. It doesn't cost any extra money or work. If your site is completely static, then it'll just use less CPU time. So if you have a high traffic site on a VPS plan, you might save on that, or you might be able to stay on a shared hosting plan for longer. But don't expect to save any money just because you don't use PHP/MySQL.

Comment: A downvote? Really? Any explanation why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Google AppEngine](https://appengine.google.com/), which is free for moderate traffic levels.

Comment: Is it possible to store just an HTML page on there?

Comment: @Kinopiko: Yes.

Comment: It requires using some special tool to upload so I think this is a stupid idea.

Comment: @Kinopiko: It still works, and works very well.  I've hosted all of my blog's static content on it.  However, it has very aggressive caching.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/ which is 'pay for what you use' and is incredibly affordable for tiny sites.

Comment: This also has a "static" option for non-PHP, non-CGI sites, making it even cheaper for those who only use HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The best and totally free option is [Dropbox](http://db.tt/2K5URA1) see details here http://wealthybohemian.com/?p=1153

Answer (score 0):

[A Small Orange](http://www.asmallorange.com/hosting/shared/) has a very low-end plan that's probably about as cheap as it's going to get($25/year) without just being free. It's still going to have PHP, etc. but you're just going to have to deal with it. It's not going to be worth any host's time to create a configuration without. It's easier for you to just not use them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a single page like this too. I use freehostia host: http://www.freehostia.com/

For free, it is a great value and easy to use! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [www.tsohost.co.uk](http://www.tsohost.co.uk) - they have a £14 a year plan which is actually very good.